# Searching PDF file for specific word then saving that specific PDF page C#

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I am trying to create an app which will search through a bulk PDF file for a letterID (eg 1234567) which is inputted via a textbox. If it locates it it will then save that specific page to a new document. I'm currently using PDFSharp but I'm struggling to find anything online that resembles what I am trying to achieve.

UPDATE: I have solved my issue and managed to get a working result from it! Will update thread tomorrow with code as it may help others.

```
 private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string letterID = txtLetterID.Text;

        // Open the input file in Import Mode
        PdfDocument inputPDFFile = PdfReader.Open(path, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
        PdfDictionary dictionary = new PdfDictionary(inputPDFFile);

        string id = dictionary.Elements.GetString(letterID);
        //Get the total pages in the PDF
        var totalPagesInInputPDFFile = inputPDFFile.PageCount;

        if (id.Equals(letterID))
        {
            //Create an instance of the PDF document in memory
            PdfDocument outputPDFDocument = new PdfDocument();

            // Add a specific page to the PdfDocument instance
            outputPDFDocument.AddPage(inputPDFFile.Pages[totalPagesInInputPDFFile - 1]);

            //save the PDF document
            SaveOutputPDF(outputPDFDocument, totalPagesInInputPDFFile);

        } 
        else
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Letter ID not found in this set of letters";
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what does your code do right now? Does it ever go into the `if` section?

Comment: Gets to the if section but tells me string id is empty, however letterID does hae a value so unsure if its just not searching the pdf or what

Comment: Why does your code sample get the page totalpages - 1? Seems to me you are just saving the last page and not the page containing the search text?